# Sum all Flags in one row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sas, proc

I had to create 5 flags in my dataset, per member record. Now the final requirement is to sum all the flags for each member.

For eg, one member has - Y,Y,,,Y i.e 3 flags set to Y. I need sum of these as 3 in my last created sum field.

I am doing this in Oracle ( Proc SQL in SAS)

Please help somebody!!

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

1. Use CATX to combine all into one field
2. Use COUNTC to count them all.

   ```
    select countc(catx(', ', flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5), 'Y') as num_y
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `case`:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when flag1 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when flag2 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when flag3 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when flag4 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when flag5 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as num_ys
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the 5 flags, then use regexp_count() to count the "Y"s. the following also allows for upper/lower case if that is an issue.

```
select regexp_count(flag1||flag2||flag3||flag4||flag5,'[yY]')
```

*Oracle 10g and up*

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a reconfiguration of the table to ingest 1,0 for Y,N. If possible.

If not, oracle has a regexp_count. Concatenate the fields then regexp_count.

Answer (score 0):

user9026530 specifically said he is using SAS, here is a pure SQL solution involving no SAS functions:

```
WITH
    aset
    AS
        (SELECT 'Y' flag1
              , 'N' flag2
              , 'Y' flag3
              , 'Y' flag4
              , NULL flag5
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT aset.*, LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (flag1 || flag2 || flag3 || flag4 || flag5, '[^Y]', NULL)) flag_count
  FROM aset


FLAG1 FLAG2 FLAG3 FLAG4 FLAG5 FLAG_COUNT
  Y     N     Y     Y           3
```